# bash script always gets --color=auto as an argument

Tags: bash, arguments

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

STUB=`pwd | awk -F '/' '{print "/" $2 "/" $3 "/"}'`
printf "arguments are $@\n"

if [ $STUB = "/mnt/nas/" ]; then

        /usr/bin/ad ls $@ 1>&1

else

        /bin/ls $@ 1>&1

fi
```

Somehow, however, whenever I run it the follwing text is automatically added as an argument even though I never typed it:

```
--color=auto
```

So I can run the following command:

```
ls
```

and it will always print

```
arguments are --color=auto
```

Even though I never typed that in.

This extra argument is messing up my script because /usr/bin/ad cannot parse it.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you run `type ls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess: the script is called `ls` and you've defined `ls` as an alias for `ls --color=auto` in `~/.bashrc` or elsewhere.

Comment: bingo.  That was it.  I am trying to override ls when I am within a certain directory tree.I feel a bit foolish now :)

Answer (score 2):

You've probably defined an alias somewhere.

Type this into terminal and see what you get:

```
alias | grep "ls"
```

You can run `ls` using the absolute path:

```
/usr/bin/ad `which ls` $@ 1>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  As it happens I had ls aliased to ls --color=auto in my .bashrc file.  I will need to edit my script and make sure it discards any non-usable arguments when passed to /usr/bin/ad.